# Which Filesystem Hierarchy Standard is in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, filesystem

> Which File system Hierarchy Standard Does Ubuntu 12.04 Using ? & What are the changes ?

On [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) the latest version is v3.0 (2012-07-01)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to understand the Ubuntu file system layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version is still 2.3 (2004) and Ubuntu, like Debian, is based on that. At the [Linux Foundation](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) it is noted that

> The FHS 3 specification is currently under development.

They aimed to release it by 1 July this year as [this article](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/fhs) describes, so the date you saw on wikipedia was merely this date they had earmarked. It hasn't actually been released yet at the time I am writing (12 September 2012). The changes haven't been decided fully, but there are some useful links in the link above (such as the fhs [mailing-lists discussion](https://lists.linux-foundation.org/mailman/listinfo/fhs-discuss) and there is a discussion at [lwn.net](https://lwn.net/Articles/441589/).

More details on the existing specifications are available at the [Linux Foundation](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/FHS).

---

For more general information, two great questions on this site explain the filesystem hierarchy well:

- [How to understand the Ubuntu file system layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/165677/which-book-should-i-buy-to-learn-file-system-in-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks alot ...very good links ..the current FHS are in my notes..preparing for lpic exam

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned version **FHS 3.0** is still in [**Draft 01 state**](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/fhs-30-draft-1) . As above in [Mik's answer](https://askubuntu.com/users/76204/mik) , they aimed for July release but not yet finalized.

Ubuntu will most probably inherit the [Debian FHS standard](http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/ubuntu-policy/policy.html/ch-opersys.html) as mentioned in [The Ubuntu-Policy](http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/ubuntu-policy/policy.html/ch-opersys.html) also locally available under **/var/share/doc/ubuntu-policy/fhs** provided you install [ubuntu-policy](http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/ubuntu-policy/policy.html/ch-opersys.html) package to see the implemented File System in Ubuntu.

If you are concerned with what does Ubuntu Implements of Standard FHS 2.3 and changes or makes exception to it , to integrate itself within it .

> The following exceptions to the FHS apply:
>
> The optional rules related to user specific configuration files for
>   applications are stored in the user's home directory are relaxed. It
>   is recommended that such files start with the '.' character (a "dot
>   file"), and if an application needs to create more than one dot file
>   then the preferred placement is in a subdirectory with a name starting
>   with a '.' character, (a "dot directory"). In this case it is
>   recommended the configuration files not start with the '.' character.
>
> The requirement for amd64 to use /lib64 for 64 bit binaries is
>   removed.
>
> The requirement that /usr/local/share/man be "synonymous" with
>   /usr/local/man is relaxed to a recommendation.
>
> The requirement that windowmanagers with a single configuration file
>   call it system.*wmrc is removed, as is the restriction that the window
>   manager subdirectory be named identically to the window manager name
>   itself.
>
> The requirement that boot manager configuration files live in /etc,
>   or at least are symlinked there, is relaxed to a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

FHS 3.0 is actual version: [The LSB workgroup is happy to announce the release of FHS 3.0.](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/lsb/fhs-30)

[Ubuntu is based on Debian](https://ubuntu.com/community/debian), which [follows it, but with exceptions, when it breaks other parts of Debian Policy](https://debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html).