# System in low-graphics mode

Tags: permissions, graphics, chmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I am totally new to Linux, and Ubuntu.

I bought ASUS X53E Notebook, erased Windows and installed Ubuntu. First it worked ok.

Then when I started working with it, I opened the terminal, entered `sudo chmod 666 /usr` and then all the icons from the main panel disappeared + the whole system stopped responding.

I decided to restart the system. When restarted, a message appears:

> the system is running in low graphics mode

and below it:

> Your screen, graphics card and input device setting could not be detected correctly. 
>   You will need to configure it yourself.

But the "OK" button is disabled and if I press any buttons nothing happens.

If I enter `Ctrl-Alt-F2` it opens the bash terminal. But there commands `sudo` or `apt-get` are not found and it says that `permission denied` if i try to enter any folder like `cd /usr`

If I enter the `su` command it asks for the password I don't know.

When encountering this problem first, I reinstalled the whole Ubuntu. but today it happened again just the same.

What shall I do?

Comment: What was your intention in doing so?

Comment: I thought that my programs should be installed in that directory. Which directory is usually used to install AMP part of LAMP, java and other applications?

Comment: To get an idea on what belongs where I'd recommend checking [the filesystem documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview#Main_directories).

Comment: I have just checked it, but it says that bin directory contains most of users applications? If it so, why is it corrupted when I change the access permissions on it?

Comment: I actually did not copy or remove or alter anything in the folder

Comment: Just check the answer of @Anwar. You removed the execution rights in the folder. With no execution rights the applications aren't allowed to run at all. This will corrupt the functionality of your system.

Comment: ahhhh now I got it....i should have made it as 777..stupid(( thanl you much

Comment: :) you are welcome. Now I see what you wanted to do! Note: you can edit rights more safely with the `+x +r +w` options for `chmod`. For the start they are much more easy to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have just corrupted the permission settings of important system files. You won't be able to use the system normally.

By using `666` as permission settings, you successfully removed the execution bit from the `/usr/` directory, so no files in it can be accessed. And as far as I know, the unity program resides in `/usr/bin` directory which is of course failing to execute.

The only option is reinstalling Ubuntu again. And ***please don't `chmod` system files without knowing exactly what you were doing***.

Check these links:

- [Linux permissions - Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Permissions)
- [Why do directories need the executable (X) permission to be opened?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened)
- [Which Filesystem Hierarchy Standard is in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/187019/61218)

The last link will give you information about the system files and folders

Comment: Could you please specify which directories are the ones never to change permissions?

Comment: I didn't say you should never change permission. but You should be knowing it before doing. The directories are: all directories without your home . That is `/usr/` /bin`, `/sbin` and such. It is generally ok to change permission in `/home/your-username-here` directories, since those are your files

Comment: @ArtemMoskalev you can check the last link, it will give you indication about the system folders

Comment: non-recursive `chmod` is easily reversible. You can fix the permissions from a live session

Answer (score 0):

After reboot try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Log into console and try `sudo chmod 755 /usr`.

Comment: @Anwar, i've looked at my own filesystem about /usr. And i know that `chmod` without -R key does not affects on "everything under". So... let's repair /usr because "everything under" is not broken.

Comment: I cant see recursion in text showed.

Comment: this won't work because `sudo` is in `/usr/bin`