# Error: The system is running in low-graphics mode in Ubuntu 14.04 Samsung np270e4e-k05mx

Tags: drivers, graphics, 14.04, intel-graphics, samsung

I'm trying the distribution Ubuntu 14.04 and when I start sometimes appears the error 'The System is running in low graphics mode', so I reboot and if I am lucky it will start normally but is annoying be doing that, so what I can do?.

My computer is a Samsung np270e4e-k05mx

http://www.samsung.com/mx/consumer/monitor-peripherals-printer/ultra-mobile-pc/ativ-book-performance/NP270E4E-K05MX

Screen:
LED HD de 14" (1,366 x 768), antirreflejante

Graphics:
Intel® HD 4000

I put the features of the screen because I think is in it the problem.

I'm a beginner on Ubuntu, so i don't know what the problem is, but I tried some of the solutions in other questions, how to reinstall the ubuntu-desktop or sudo apt-get install fglrx, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error or this http://askubuntu.com/questions/196382/system-in-low-graphics-mode ?

Comment: yes, I have read it, but I hadn't tried all the responses, I find the solution doing this:

ctrl + alt + f1
sudo apt-get install gdm
choose gdm
sudo reboot

and I got login without the error :D

but  I miss lightdm graphic ambiance :( nah finally it doesn't matter.

thanks it was very usefull to me.

Answer (score 1):

OP's own answer:

I found the solution doing this: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

choose gdm

```
sudo reboot
```

and I got login without the error