# Install Ubuntu on 64-bit PC alongside Win7; Will Ubuntu see Windows partition?

Tags: 12.04, helpfile

Acer w/ AMD Athlon 64 x2 dual core 3800+ 2.00 GHz, 4 gig RAM, 32 bit Windows 7, originally built for Windows Vista. Added an NVIDIA graphics card.

1 TB barracuda hard drive partitioned into 3, 1 partition [201GB] set aside for Ubuntu, 
Win 7 on one and files on the third.

I want to put Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on the empty partition to work alongside Windows. Am also concerned, as I read that Ubuntu 64bit may not see the existing Windows installation – especially if it is a 32 bit program.

Can anyone tell me the safest and most effective means of installation ?

Comment: (1) You will be able to see the NTFS partitions used by Windows, open, change, and delete files using Ubuntu apps. (2) You can use a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Ubuntu; the break point is typically 2GB, so I'd go 64-bit for better performance. (3) It's recommended to create two new partitions; an ext3 partition for Ubuntu programs and data, and a swap partition of 4GB.

Comment: @K7AAY — why `ext3` and not `ext4`? `ext4` is faster especially with file system checks.

Comment: User240172, please repost your second question so it may be answered separately. And, I stand corrected. The default version is ext4 with 12.04 LTS and it is indeed superior.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kevin Wyamn who answered this at [Installing Ubuntu 12.04 along Windows XP and Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207052/installing-ubuntu-12-04-along-windows-xp-and-windows-7)

You can install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 just fine. Assuming you're trying to go the easiest route, boot from your Ubuntu LIVE DVD/USB and select "Install Ubuntu".

In the very early steps it will ask you what you want to do:

- Install Ubuntu Alongside [existing Operating System/s]. This will
  replace Windows MBR bootloader with GRUB/GRUB2 bootloader. **USE THIS**
- Replace [existing Operating System/s] with Ubuntu (this will format
  your entire drive and install Ubuntu). Like above, this will include
  the GRUB/GRUB2 bootloader.
- Something Else (this is for if you have created a partition
  explicitly for Ubuntu with the appropriate file format [ext4] and
  want to install Ubuntu here). This is a bit trickier though because
  the installer will expect the drive to be bootable.

You'll be presented with a menu [GRUB/GRUB2] during the boot process (as long as there is more than one Operating System present) that will allow you to choose which operating system you want to start up from.