# Access Rights Problem: USB Device Read as User

Tags: server, 20.04, permissions, raspberrypi, input

I am trying to access an  [USB device](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/accessories/adapters/wireless-adapter-windows) as `$USER`  running some Python Code based on [this GIT repo](https://github.com/medusalix/xone). I am running **Ubuntu 20.04 Server** on a **RaspberryPi4b**. It works fine as root

`sudo python3 myPythonCode.py`

but **not** as `$USER`  i.e.

`python3 myPythonCode.py`

which leads me to believe it's an Access Rights Problem. I tried

1. `sudo chown $USER /dev/usb/`
2. `sudoedit /etc/udev/rules.d/50-myusb.rules` and add line `KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]",MODE="0666"` to file
3. `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`

The device is mounted obviously `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:02fe Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But it does not show up in `/dev/ttyUSB` but you can find it in `/dev/bus/usb/001/005` (duh). `dmesg | tail`:

```
[  210.127161] input: Microsoft X-Box One pad as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/gip0/gip0.0/input/input1
[  998.563321] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1018.975089] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 1019.076591] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02fe, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1019.076607] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1019.076619] usb 1-1.4: Product: XBOX ACC
[ 1019.076630] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Microsoft Inc.
[ 1019.076640] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 430112
[ 1019.163760] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 1022.292169] input: Microsoft X-Box One pad as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/gip0/gip0.0/input/input2
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Add `$USER` to `input` group

```
sudo usermod -a -G input $USER
```

and everything works like a charm.

**Long Version:** Thank you for reading. I will not edit my question, so anybody can see my earlier ignorance, but here is some insight:

Not all USB devices are TTY. This is true for Serial Communication via USB (the only way I had seen before), hence the USB dongle does not mount as `/dev/ttyUSB ...`, so most of my semi-ignorant solutions were bullshit. Actually human interface devices are mounted at `/dev/input/` which can be read by adding your user to the `input` group. To continue please read [askubuntu.com/questions/210895/what-are-the-files-in-dev-input-and-what-they-do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210895/what-are-the-files-in-dev-input-and-what-they-do).

Also, when using `threading` package, errors will not be thrown if happens within thread, unless the developer explicitly implements it, see [stackoverflow.com/questions/2829329/catch-a-threads-exception-in-the-caller-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829329/catch-a-threads-exception-in-the-caller-thread).