# Why does Linux/Ubuntu have an unorganised install solution?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

I started using Windows 7 again to play some of my games I had been missing and I have to say I've been relieved to be reintroduced to the standard installation area `Program Files`.

From what I've noticed on almost every Linux distribution there is like 5 different areas where games/programs or other odds and ends end up. When you install something, I feel as though you pretty much have to guess where it installed at, which honestly don't make any sense to me.

So my question is, why does it appear as though there is no standard on Linux/Ubuntu? I'm not saying it's a bad thing. I just want to understand the reasons behind it.

Comment: For more information on the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS), see http://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/ and http://askubuntu.com/questions/165677/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why is there no standard on Linux/Ubuntu?

The reason is that it *is* part of a standard. It's called the ["Filesystem Hierarchy Standard"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

I suggest you to read that.

Your conclusion should be is that it is *way* more organized than you think it is and in my opinion *a lot* better than on Windows OS.

Comment: Ubuntu or even Linux in general is _way_ more organized than windows

Comment: If you know how it works maybe. If you aren't really familiar with it it's a bit rough around the edges. Thats why I'm asking about it to hopefully make my Linux experience more enjoyable...which actually already has.. Thanks guys. I didn't know anything about the FHS. :)

Comment: @Matthew No problem. But just don't make assumptions ("no standard") if you don't know about it. An open attitude will help you in a general way to find out "how stuff works".

Comment: I should have reworded what I said, I meant that from what I "already know" it looks unorganized and as though there are no standards. Sorry about that.