# How to install Audacity's manual?

Tags: installation, install-from-source, audacity

I am trying to find the Audacity Folder so I can add the manual to it so I don't have to use online resources for help. I can't find where Ubuntu 12.04 stores the Applications Folder (as in a Mac)

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't store all of a programs stuff in one folder like Windows and Mac.  See: http://askubuntu.com/q/138547/44179

Answer (score 5):

If you downloaded the Audacity manual from [their official download](http://code.google.com/p/audacity/downloads/detail?name=audacity-manual-2.0.3.zip&can=2&q=manual) site, these commands will work:

`cd` to the Downloads folder:

```
cd Downloads
```

Extract the manual:

```
unzip audacity-manual-2.0.3.zip
```

Then move the `help` folder into `/usr/share/audacity`:

```
sudo mv help /usr/share/audacity
```

There you go.  Audacity now has a local copy of the manual.