# Cannot Partition Using GParted

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, gparted

Here's [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbX7t.png) that might help. Basically, I'm trying to partition this hard drive which currently only has Ubuntu 13.04. However, GParted does not allow me to do anything. When I click on "Unmount", it shows [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqhGL.png). And so, I basically can't do anything to make a partition. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Trying to change partition of a running Ubuntu system is like trying to change a tire while driving the car. Boot the computer using live CD/DVD/USB and choose "Try Ubuntu." Run Gparted from there.

Comment: Do you know what will happen if you (did) unmount `/`? [Everything will die](http://askubuntu.com/a/138551/176889) (basically)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna change the partition of the running system(?), Shut it down, and use a usb or livecd installer to do the changes.

Comment: I tried to boot from the Windows 7 Recover Pack CD (I was trying to make the partition so that I can install Win7), but it refuses to let me boot from the CD.

Comment: Boot with the media you installed ubuntu from? And then use ` GParted ` to size it?

Comment: I made the partitions just now. But I still cannot install Win7 in the partition because it keeps saying that it can't find a partition greater than 829 MB. I have a 248 GB partition sitting right there in my hard drive, but this CD seems to be unable to recognize it. Here's [a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/FZ71G4R.png).

Comment: You need to use a boot enabled media(CD\DVD\USB eg.) and tell your computer to use it right after powering the computer on. After you have installed ubuntu will you most likely need to repair your grub2.

Comment: How do I repair grub2?

Comment: I meant after installing windows, you most likely need to [repair grub.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install windows you should not run the cd or dvd inside ubuntu..First use a live ubuntu usb or dvd, re-size or format the ext4 partition using gparted and create a new ntfs partition with the space you got, then restart the system with windows dvd and install it in the newly created ntfs partition..

NOTE: The new partition should not be a extended partition..once you install windows grub will not show up and you also won't be able to find ubuntu option in windows boot page so i highly recommend you to install windows first then install ubuntu in a separate partition...