# Knowing the interface of ubuntu and editing them

Tags: 12.04, interface

Where are the files for the desktop or the interface that appears on the screen stored?
And how can we edit them. How are they programmed? 
What programming language is used to built the interfaces?

Comment: Please ask one question per thread. All your questions are interesting but don't post them in only one thread.

Comment: like @MrVaykadji says above, please try to be more specific to what kind of interface you're talking about.. _(visit [Ubuntu file system layout](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout) to learn where/how system and configuration files are organised)_

Comment: @MrVaykadji  am I specific now with this edit?

Comment: @MrVaykadji It seems (especially considering your answer) that this was really, in effect, one narrowly-scoped question after all. A good general rule is that if you can make a good, short answer to the whole question, then it's okay for it to be just one question. **algosig**: I've rolled your question back to the way it was before, which I think was actually fine. But feel free to edit further or even undo the rollback if you prefer to change it; I won't get in the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after some diggin', it's all basically written in `C`, `C++` and `Vala`.

[This link](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/) will provide you informations about Unity Development. [This one](https://developer.gnome.org/) is for Gnome project (Unity is based on Gnome).

You can check the source code of Unity on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/unity). You can use the source code to edit your interface, it's under *GNU GPL v3* licence.

Most of the end-user files are editable with a text-editor (such as gedit, nano), but don't expect much, it isn't as easy to modify as XFCE, for example.

Some strings are stored in dconf, which you can check and modify using `dconf-tools` or `gsettings`

Comment: Thank you @MrVaykadji This helped me .I came to know something more about the GNOME

Comment: yeah i agreed you @algosig