# Why there is no need to give path as in windows to reffer other application from one package

Tags: 12.04, java, video, vlc, netbeans

I connected mysql with c++ in ubuntu , used GCC compiler from terminal that time i didn't give any path for mysql.h. 
and i wanted to play video using vlcj in java swings. In the program we need to give two paths :
1. where the vlc player is installed (In windows, it is c://Program Files//Video Lan//VLC)
2. The Video file we want to play in swings.

when i tried to play it on ubuntu using netbeans. First i give path for vlc installed is 
usr/share/vlc , it did work , then tried some more options , where vlc files are lying. 
but i was not succeeded.  then i got to know from someone that there is not need to give path in ubuntu. but we have pass an argument to JVM when we run the code.

My First question is why we do not need to give path in ubuntu. (Plz tell me in detail, i love to learn Linux , thank u)

Second question is still i am not succeed in playing video using vlcj in ubuntu swings java, using Netbeans IDE 8 and JDK 8 and latest version of vlcj i.e version 3

(i know it is askUbuntu , not java Fourms, if u could suggest me something plz do so)

Comment: Regarding the second question: Ask a new question with details: a short code snippet showing what you have tried, how you run it, what errors you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, different applications keep all their files, including the executable files in their own folders. In Linux, the norm is that all applications use the standard folders instead (`/bin`, or `/usr/bin` for executables, `/lib`, or `/usr/lib` for libraries, etc.). Since the standard binary folders are all in the default PATH, you usually don't need to add application-specific folders to the PATH  manually.

However, if you install an application to a nonstandard location, then you'll need to add that location to the PATH manually.

Further reading:

- [How to understand the Ubuntu file system layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout)