# How does Ubuntu install .deb files?

Tags: software-installation, packaging

I want to know how does Ubuntu install software. For instance I know that executables are moved in `/usr/bin` and `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` but I want to know why and know more about it.

Comment: Check this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Comment: I am not sure what kind of answer you are looking for: *how* or *why*. The last one would be a quite (too?) extensive answer, and include history etc. *What* it is is probably done easier then *why*.

Comment: " I know that executables are moved in  /usr/bin" ehm... or `/sbin/` or `/bin/` or `/usr/sbin/` :P

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/a/138551/15811 Where files are installed should(!) be dictated by the FHS.

Comment: ....and http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/fhs.html