# What is the purpose of the bin directory?

Tags: filesystem, directory

What is the purpose of the bin directory? What are some examples?

Comment: The usage of bin directory is which it contains many commands, scripts and more number of executable files and it is mainly for executing the above in order to accomplish a task.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout/138551#138551

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> /bin — Essential command binaries that need to be available in single
>   user mode; for all users, e.g., cat, ls, cp.

This Wikipedia article may be useful for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Answer (score 1):

bin directory contains executable files that you have in your system..its like program files if we compare to MS windows .every user individually will have a bin directory which has his own executables...and there is also sbin directory which will have system level programs