# Can I install Ubuntu and use it like I did with Windows XP?

Tags: system-installation, windows, dell, windows-xp

I use an Dell Inspiron 1501 with Windows XP.  I am interested in getting a new OS for some reasons and security. I already have little experience with unix from my time in university.

I use this notebook for the internet, with skype and chrome and firefox.

Can I install Ubuntu and use it like I did with XP? Without issues?

Thanks for reading and answering.

Comment: Yes, of course. But first of all learn some about linux filesystem layout, as it is totally different for Windows. And have a look at some nice tutorials on the web.I'm posting some links here and good luck with Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-Linux

Comment: I used unix & linux for years without having a full detailed understanding of the filesystem, not required, especially for "plain" desktop/internet use. And the OP should already be at least vaguely familiar with the unix filesystem. I'd say the key difference is that anything can be mounted anywhere, it's more "virtual", unlike Windows XP where a partition (`C:\`) is always seen as it is "on disk"

Comment: Basically, yes, as 'internet, with skype and chrome and firefox' all work very well under Ubuntu (and many other Linux distros :)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had to make the same decision for an older computer (12 years old). I've been through Windows 7, Elementary OS, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Went back to Windows XP, and finally back to Xubuntu.

The point is your going to have to experiment and figure out what's best for your computer so have a look around and try some of them?

However, I would recommend you try one or more of the following: Xubuntu, Elementary OS, Lubuntu, Linux Mint. They are considered to be lightweight and suitable for older hardware. Hope this helps.

Comment: Linux Mint XFCE may be better for very old hardware, the regular Cinnamon edition of Mint (similar to the regular Unity Ubuntu) has higher requirements

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it will be like Windows, no it will *not be* Windows...**  [Ubuntu and its official derivatives](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are based on GNU/Linux, which is a completely different animal then Windows XP which is based on DOS, Windows 1.0, Windows 286/386, Window for WorkGroups, Windows NT, Windows 2000 leading up to Windows XP.

- Linux was from the start designed as a multi-user, multi-network, multi-tasking open system.
- The origins of Windows are in a single-user, no network, single-tasking system.

So the philosophy is completely different, and every now and then you'll run into something that just doesn't *seem to* make sense, but when you dig deeper, you'll notice *that it does* just different from what you're used to.

So, hang in there and don't despair: **you're going to migrate from a mainstream boring car to a highly customized racing minivan** that can do all you did before, but it's just not a sedan and any and all pieces can be customized (Want electric? Go ahead! Left rear view mirror with built-in shades?  Go ahead!)

Just don't go crazy and start customizing straight away!  Learn to have the tools you have, and especially have a look [here on how to install software when you're a Windows user](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926)