# Neuroimaging Use: How big for partitions (root, home, swap) and some other Qs

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, root, swap

I will be using my Ubuntu for neuroimaging use. This is my first time using -- I've been using Macs for the last few years so am not familiar with using Ubuntu on a regular PC. A few questions: Are root, swap, and home partitions necessary? I plan to install Ubuntu on an  HDD (1TB), with my Windows on a separate SSD (256GB).

My specs are as follows:

Processor: i7, 3.6GHz, RAM: 32GB

I am wondering what I should do to 'max' it out, as I plan to run pretty intensive imaging analyses on Ubuntu. I will only be using Windows for Office and probably SPSS and Matlab. If necessary, how big should each partition likely be given this context?

In addition, I would like to dual boot. The advice given has been quite scattered and confusing thus far, so I'd like to confirm this here. I guess the more ideal choice would be to boot Windows from Ubuntu and not the other way around. If so, what should I select in the 'device for boot loader installation'  option when installing? Should it be the sda (Windows disk) or the sdb (Ubuntu)?

Thanks very much.

-M.

Comment: These are 3 very different questions in one. We can not answer these in one single answer. Let me suggest to split your question asking each issue in a separate question. Some of your questions may already be answered however. See e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported  http://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout or http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games

Answer (score 0):

As to part 1 of this post:   Swap with those specs is purely a preference but even /home is not required BUT given your use case HIGHLY HIGHLY recommended as /home is where all those imaging files will go NOT root (/).

as for part 2 of this post: you will need to better define "maxing it out"  but also of note  LibreOffice and kingsoft Office  are BOTH in ubuntu repos and do 98% of Office suite  / mathlab is as well,

I personally would have bootloaders on both drives with the primary OS having  control of the loader on that disk(s)  using winboot  for the (mostly) windows drve and grub on the linux drive.

Comment: In that case, how big should /home be? Thanks very much for your response!

Comment: Assuming os i installed in the ssd  75% of it