# On an upgrade will ubuntu erase a folder created in the root directory?

Tags: directory

I have a habit of creating a folder called `soft` inside the root directory, as in `/soft`. I usually put manually installed softwares there.

My question is if I perform an upgrade such as `14.10 -> 15.04` will ubuntu erase that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Only if you re-install from scratch with a format, should it be deleted. Also, the `/opt/` directory is already standardized as a place to install things manually to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you also provide proof such as in a documentation?

Comment: See for proof http://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout/138551#138551  There is no /soft. But I would suggest you reconsider this directory: it is better to keep / clean and install 3rd party software in the directory it is intended to go: /opt/{software-name}/ as dobey noted :)