# click.ubuntu.com folder in /opt

Tags: directory, click-packages

Well I found a folder in `/opt` from which I don't know the origin.

When I do `ls -la /opt` it gives me

```
marten@marten-desktop:~$ ls -la /opt/
insgesamt 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096 Sep 12 23:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root     root     4096 Sep  9 15:44 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 clickpkg clickpkg 4096 Aug 13 13:45 click.ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 Jul  9 21:49 google
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is software you installed yourself (/opt/ is purely used for 3rd party applications you install yourself from mostly pre-compiled archives (tar.gz or something similar) and *not* from USC or a debian install file (if software did automatically get installed there from Ubuntu Software Center or even a debian installer (.DEB). The [FileSystem Hierarchy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout/138551#138551)  we use has a strict rule on using /opt/)).

What you installed is probably [clickpkg](https://github.com/sonrisesoftware/tasks-app/blob/master/clickpkg) as part of their [Ubuntu tasks app](https://github.com/sonrisesoftware/tasks-app) set (Ubuntu Tasks is a task management app written for Ubuntu Touch as part of the Ubuntu App Showdown.).

---

/opt/ is not used by "apt-get". If you want to get rid of it all you need to do to is`sudo rm -rf /opt/clickpkg`. All software related to it -must- be in that directory when using /opt/ as an installation location.

Comment: Well I think it's like Google Chrome or Spotify which also install in `/opt`. So do you know from which package it is? Because I want to `apt-get` remove it.

Comment: /opt/ is not used by "apt-get". All you need to do to get rid of it is `sudo rm -rf /opt/clickpkg`. All software related to it -must- be in that directory when using /opt/ as an installation location.

Comment: Okay thank you but Spotify and Google Chrome do install to `/opt`. Spotify has a ppa and Google Chrome is a Debian Package so why do they install to `/opt`?

Comment: Both are 3rd party applications. 3rd party applications go to /opt/. Regardless on how you install it (aptana, jasperserver and many many more install into /opt/). BTW: if you install it with a PPA and it is installed in /opt (and that install was not with a separate installations ;) ) removing software from /opt/ is always possible with `rm /opt/{software}`: that is the intention of opt: -all- parts of the software go there.

Comment: What if the click package has a  `/usr/bin` file, this has to removed too I guess ?

Comment: I did not install `clickpkg` or any kind of task app, yet still there is this (empty) directory in `/opt`.