# What are the differences of "/" and "/home" separately

Tags: format

When i format my dekstop i use "/" and "/Home" as ext4 journaling file system.
What are the differences  between "/" and  "/home"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/home` directory is the directory in which all the directories which belong to users are stored, so for instance if your username is `sandwich` then your home directory (where all the stuff to do with your user is stored) will be in `/home/sandwhich` (also known as `~`).

The `/` directory which is known as the 'root' directory is the directory in which all other directories are. So for instance these are all the folders and files in a standard root directory:

```
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib64       mnt   root  srv  usr      vmlinuz.old
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  lost+found  opt   run   sys  var
cdrom  home  lib             media       proc  sbin  tmp  vmlinuz
```

Each has its own use (for instance you will even see the `home` directory in there). For more information on the other directories in the root directory please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/138562/364819).