# Difference between cd / and cd ~

Tags: command-line, filesystem

Could someone give me an explanation of the difference between `cd /` and `cd ~`

Also, what is the difference when using the same command at administrator level?

Comment: You can also just `cd` with no arguments and it will go home, just like `cd ~` if you get tired of pushing those extra buttons for this common use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd /` changes the directory to root of the filesystem, which is `/`

while `cd ~` changes it to your home directory.

Here `~` is interpreted as the home folder of the user who is executing the command. For me it is `/home/anwar`.

If you run `cd ~` as root, that will change the working directory to root users home, which is at `/root`. `root` users home folder does not typically reside under `/home/` directory, instead it is found directly under root directory `/`.

Check this question for a general introduction to Linux Filesystem

- [How to understand the Ubuntu file system layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout/138551#138551)

Answer (score 0):

*Please note: In the original question, the paths are **not** the same, and those commands are not equal.*

`cd /`

This changes to the / (root) directory of the system. It's a hardcoded path, and will go to the same directory no matter what user executes it.

`cd ~`

This is a shell shortcut that always references the user's home directory.

If user "raj" executes cd ~, and their home directory is /home/raj, it will take raj to /home/raj.

If user "babna" executes cd ~, and their home directory is /home/babna, it will take babna to /home/babna.

If the same command is executed as root, it will take you to /root on a typical Ubuntu system.

This is *very* useful for scripting, since multiple users can use the same script and affect changes to their home directory.

For single commands input manually into bash, **so long as the paths end up the same**, it doesn't matter how they're input, since cd *itself* is a shell built-in which will use the same mechanism to switch directories.