# Using multiple hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I moved recently (like, yesterday) from Windows to Ubuntu. My computer has one SSD and one HDD, and I installed the operating system on the SSD. Now, I would like to keep most of my things in the HDD, but use the SSD for important stuff. In Windows, the drives were clearly different, but I don't understand how I can do this in Ubuntu. So, how can I use both drives, and how do I know where I'm installing/downloading/etc applications and/or files? I haven't done anything yet, so everything should be completely at a "starting point". Also, I am completely new to Ubuntu.

Comment: The HDD's partitions should be clearly visible in the left panel of the file browser. Those icons should be clickable, and should take you to their corresponding partitions.

Comment: This is a very large question, and I am marking to close it as a duplicate of [https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout).  Basically, all of the disk structure starts at `/`, the root of the file system.  Each directory under `/` (/home for example) can actually be a separate disk, a separate partition on a single disk, or a simple sub-directory of the root directory.  Additionally, links are often used to redirect an inconvenient directory name...

Answer (score 1):

Linux operating systems organize the file system in a tree structure. Since you installed the OS to your SSD, that drive is the root of the tree and is mounted at `/` Where on the tree the HDD is depends on how and where you mount it. It can be anywhere on the tree you desire. (One common location to mount a secondary drive on a home system is `/home` as that is the location on the tree that by default holds all the users files. For a good overview, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview