# Replacing windows with ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, windows-8, disk

Now I am running windows 8.1 on my laptop.I have 3 disks(C,D,E).Windows 8.1 files are in C disk.Now I want to replace windows 8.1 with ubuntu 17.10.1. How can I keep my D & E safe and install ubuntu without losing any data.how the disk partition should be?

Comment: Step 0: make a backup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/343268/301745)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your hard drive is partitioned into three partitions. If so, it would be much safer to install Ubuntu on a new Hard Drive, and then drag and drop everything from D and E over to the new drive.

If you want to take chances and install Ubuntu onto the partition that contained the "C" drive, then make sure you can identify that partition by its size. Click on File Explorer in Windows and then right click on the C drive and select "properties". Do this for each of the drives and get the size of each. While installing Ubuntu make sure you select custom install option or "advanced" and then select the partition that matches the C drive size.

If D and E are separate drives, remove them and install Ubuntu on the internal hard drive, and then reinsert the other drives.

Comment: Why do you say "it would be much safer to install Ubuntu on a new hard drive"? Do you mean OP should make a backup?

Comment: IIRC, removing the extra drives is unnecessary except on some systems that use MBR (non-UEFI) boot.

Comment: The point about identifying partitions by size I get, but it might be easier to identify them by their order, for example if the D drive and E drive are the same size.

Comment: Overall, I'm trying to say that I don't understand the reasoning behind your methodology. Some more background info would help.

Comment: gordstar, thanks for your information .but I watched some videos on youtube and saw that there were some terms named swap, root, etc etc.how can I be clear about those terms?I never used Linux before, that's why so many questions are arising!!

Comment: @wjandrea I am only saying to install Ubuntu on a new drive to avoid wiping personal data that may be on the current drive. The user sounds as though they are hoping to install Ubuntu on a portion of the drive that contains only the critical Windows files, while keeping their personal data safe. I myself am having a hard time trying to understand what the user is trying to accomplish so I should have asked for more information in a comment rather than answering the question.

Comment: @Xahid I would highly recommend reviewing this post      https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout