# Ubuntu 12.04 is certified with LSB4.0 exactly?

Tags: lsb-release

I heard that Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS follows the LSB(*Linux Standard Base*) 4.0.

I checked the Ubuntu 12.04.4 using dist-check tool (Lsb-dist-checker-4.0.1.9-2.i486.tar.gz) for more than 12 hours to make sure it is true.
However, the test results do not comply with the LSB 4.0. How to do I understand?

Ubuntu 12.04 is LSB Certified distro, Right?

If it is true, is there a way anything else in order to confirm this?

Test result is in following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89125/does-ubuntu-follow-the-linux-standard-base-lsb and the answer is "Ubuntu is not fully compliant with LSB 4.0".

Comment: OK. I already look at it, but it is not same as mine question. I need the exactly information about lsb4.0 and ubuntu12.04. I don't think that ubuntu12.04 is not exactly certified with lsb. test result is 99.5% according to my test.